# Debug a Perl script

Tags: perl, shell

I already did some research on Perl script debugging but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Let me explain my problem here.

I have a Perl script which is not entering into last while loop it seems cos it is not printing anything inside as instructed.

So, I want to know is there any easier method available to see all lines one by one like we can see in shell script using

```
set -x
```

Here is my Perl script code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $ZONEADM = "/usr/sbin/zoneadm list -c";

use strict;
use diagnostics;
use warnings;

system("clear");
print "Enter the app\n";
chomp(my $INS = <>);

print "\nEnter the Symmitrix ID\n";
chomp(my $SYMM = <>);

print "\nEnter the Server\n";
chomp(my $SRV = <>);

print "\nEnter the devices\n";
while (<>) {
  if($_ !~ m/(q|quit)/) {    
    chomp($_);
    my $TEMP_FILE = "/export/home/ptiwari/scripts/LOG.11";
    open (my $FH, '>>', $TEMP_FILE);
    my @arr = split(/:/, $_);
    if($arr[3]) {
      print $FH "/".$INS."db/".$arr[0]."  ".$SYMM."  ".$arr[1]."  ".$arr[2]."  ".$arr[3]."\n";
    }
    else {
      print $FH "/".$INS."db/".$arr[0]."  ".$SYMM."  ".$arr[1]."  ".$arr[2]."\n";
    }
    undef @arr;
    close $FH;
  }
  else {
    exit;
  }
}

my $IS_ZONE = qx($ZONEADM|grep -i $SRV|grep -v global);
if($IS_ZONE) {
  $IS_ZONE = "yes";
}
else {
  $IS_ZONE = "no";    
}    

open(my $FLH, '<', "/export/home/ptiwari/scripts/LOG.11");
my @lines;
while(<$FLH>) {
  my ($GLOBAL_MTPT, $SYM, $SYM_DEV, $SIZE, $NEWFS) = split;
  print $GLOBAL_MTPT."  ".$SYM."  ".$SYM_DEV;
  print "\n";
}
```

I already tried `perl -d` but it didn't show me anything which can help me to troubleshoot why it didn't enter the while loop.

Comment: If you have write and read access to the file, it should go into the loop. You should check the return value of your `open` statements by adding `or die $!`.

Comment: I tried using $! but it didn't give any message. I have rw access over file

Comment: That comment doesn't say anything. You tried using it how, where? `$!` is only set when something goes wrong. If you have rw access then your open should work and `$!` would of course not be set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `while(<>)` loop doesn't have sensible termination conditions. The `/q|quit/` regex is buggy.

1. You exit the whole script if any line contains `q` or `quit`. You will also exit, if the device descriptions contains things like `quill` or `acquisition`. The effect of typing an accidental `q` is similar to a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.
2. The only way to finish the loop and go on with the script is to send an EOF. This requires the user to punch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> into the keyboard, or a file to simply end. Then your script *will* continue.

There are some other things wrong/weird with this script.
Main criticism: (a) all-uppercase variables are informally reserved for Perl and pragmatic modules. Lowercase or mixed case variables work too. (b) Your script contains quite some redundant code. Either refactor it into `sub`s, or rewrite your logic

Here is an example rewrite that may be easier to debug / may not contain some of the bugs.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

use constant DEBUG_FLAG => 1;  # set to false value for release
my $zoneadm_command = "/usr/sbin/zoneadm list -c";
my $temp_file_name = "/export/home/ptiwari/scripts/LOG.11";

sub prompt { print "\n", $_[0], "\n"; my $answer = <>; chomp $answer; return $answer }
sub DEBUG  { print STDERR "DEBUG> ", @_, "\n" if DEBUG_FLAG }

system("clear");
my $app_name = prompt("Enter the app");
my $symm_id  = prompt("Enter the Symmitrix ID");
my $server   = prompt("Enter the server name");
print "Enter the devices.\n";
print qq(\tTo terminate the script, type "q" or "quit".\n);
print qq(\tTo finish the list of devices, type Ctrl+D.\n);

open my $temp_file, ">>", $temp_file_name
    or die "Can't open log file: $!";

while (<>) {
  chomp; # remove trailing newline
  exit if /^q(?:uit)?$/; # terminate the script if the input line *is* `q` or `quit`. 
  my @field = split /:/;
  # grep: select all true values
  @field = grep {$_} ("/${app_name}db/$field[0]", $symm_id, @field[1 .. 3]);
  print $temp_file join("  ", @field), "\n";
}
close $temp_file;

DEBUG("finished the reading loop");

# get the zones with only *one* extra process
my @zones = 
    grep {not /global/}
    grep {/\Q$server\E/i}
    map  {chomp; $_}
        qx($zoneadm_command);
my $is_zone = @zones ? "yes" : "no";

DEBUG("Am I in the zone? $is_zone");

open my $device_file, "<", $temp_file_name or die "Can't open $temp_file_name: $!";

while (<$device_file>) {
  chomp;
  my ($global_mtpt, $sym, $sym_dev) = split;
  print join("  ", $global_mtpt, $sym, $sym_dev), "\n";
  # or short: print join("  ", (split)[0 .. 2]), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much amon for sharing such a nice code. It is really helpful for me. I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this for stepping into the script:

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Perl/Using-The-Perl-Debugger/

Answer (score 0):

You can really use the debugger: http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html

But if your preference is to trace like bash -x, take a look at this discussion:
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=419653

Answer (score 0):

The [Devel::Trace](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel%3a%3aTrace) Perl module is designed to mimic `sh -x` tracing for shell programs.

Answer (score -2):

Try to remove the "my $" from the last open statement and the "$" from there  in the last while statement. Or better yet, try this:

```
open(my FLH, '<', "/export/home/ptiwari/scripts/LOG.11");

my @lines = <FLH>;
foreach (@lines) {
    my ($GLOBAL_MTPT, $SYM, $SYM_DEV, $SIZE, $NEWFS) = split;
    print $GLOBAL_MTPT." ".$SYM." ".$SYM_DEV;
    print "\n";
}
```

Let me know about the results.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I can understand why. This is just bad advice. Use lexical file handles, and don't slurp the files if you don't have to. And also, it is `print "$GLOBAL_MTPT $SYM $SYM_DEV\n"`.